# Export data from word to R as well as the format of the character read

Tags: r, xml, ms-word, officer

I have a word docx, with some coloured characters. I am trying to export this data into a dataframe and want to retain the information of the font color as well. The colors represent important information and so, I would like the output to state the colour of the character being read. Are there any R packages that would help me read this?

I have tried converting it into XML, but have had no luck trying to retrieve the text based on the font color. I have also tried the officer package but unfortunately, it doesn't read the font colors.

Sample input would be a docx with characters like this:

[image]

Sample output could look something like:

```
Character   Underline   Bold    Color
 O               No          Yes      Red
 %               Yes         Yes    Black
 8               Yes         Yes    Green
```

OR

```
Character   Underline   Bold    Color
 O               No          Yes      Red
 %               Yes         Yes    Black
 8               Yes         Yes    Green
```

OR

```
Red Character positions- 1
Green Character positions- 3
Underline character positions- 2,3
Bold character positions- 1,2,3
```

Comment: Why kind of psychopath encodes information as color?

Comment: Hahaha, had the same question to the client that gave me the data like this!

Comment: I'd start with the `.docx.` version and use `read_xml(unz(file.choose(), "word/document.xml"))` (`read_xml` is from the package `xml2`), then follow this structure guide: https://www.toptal.com/xml/an-informal-introduction-to-docx

Comment: It might be worth a feature request to the maintainer of the officer package. I believe that package basically parses and edits the XML code.

Comment: Thanks @PaulStaffordAllen. As mentioned, I tried the xml2 package and reached to the point where I could get the path to all the nodes with the underlined format. But could not navigate to the corresponding text after that

Comment: Fair enough - I didn't know if you meant unzipping the .docx to extract the XML or doing save-as XLM in word.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note: my test document is about pigs, hence the variable names.

```
library(xml2)

pigsin <- read_xml(unz(file.choose(), "word/document.xml"))

text_nodeset <- pigsin |> xml2::xml_find_all("//w:r[w:t]") |> as_list()
```

This gives you a list of all sections of the document containing text.
Then iterate over them to extract the relevant text and values, e.g:

```
lapply(text_nodeset, 
       FUN = \(x) {
         out <- data.frame(chars = strsplit(unlist(x$t),""),
                    italic = !is.null(x$rPr$i),
                    bold = !is.null(x$rPr$b),
                    colour = ifelse(is.null(x$rPr$color), "-", attr(x$rPr$color, "val")))
         colnames(out) <- c("chars", "italic", "bold", "colour")
         out
       }) |> dplyr::bind_rows()
```

gives

```
   chars italic  bold colour
1      P   TRUE FALSE      -
2      i   TRUE FALSE FF0000
3      g   TRUE FALSE      -
4      P  FALSE FALSE      -
5      A  FALSE FALSE      -
6      G  FALSE FALSE FF0000
7      P  FALSE  TRUE      -
8      o  FALSE  TRUE      -
9      g  FALSE  TRUE      -
10     P  FALSE  TRUE 00B050
11     U  FALSE  TRUE 00B050
...
(# for my silly toy file)
```